# Icon bug in desktop

Tags: kde, launcher, icons, 20.04

Coming from Ubuntu 18.04, shortcuts in a folder on the desktop don't work in Ubuntu 20.04.
Some icons for LibreOffice Calc work and others, don't.
The same for Firefox.
Finally, I'm unable to modify a copy of a working shortcut. 
Please, can someone help me?

Comment: Can we have an image of what you're dealing with here? It may be an issue with broken dekstop files, which can be rectified with [bleachbit's](https://www.bleachbit.org) remove broken desktop file feature(under the system tab)

Comment: kde in the tag, yet Ubuntu mentionned which uses Gnome Shell by default? Clarify what desktop you are using.

Comment: Add an image. Make sure that enable launching is ticked in icon properties.